# how to get key sequence after sending a SIGNAL

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I bind 2 keys to call 2 methods of my class. Is it possible to call the some method and knowing which key was pressed?

```
def initGui(self):
    self.keyAction = QAction("Test Plugin", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.keyAction, self.toggle_key_1)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test plugins", self.keyAction)
    QObject.connect(self.keyAction, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.toogle_layer_1)

    self.keyAction = QAction("Test Plugin", self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.iface.registerMainWindowAction(self.keyAction, self.toggle_key_2)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu("&Test plugins", self.keyAction)
    QObject.connect(self.keyAction, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.toogle_layer_2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can know which object has triggered the signal from your slot (function) with using `QObject::sender()` function. As [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) say:

> Returns a pointer to the object that sent the signal, if called in a
>   slot activated by a signal; otherwise it returns 0. The pointer is
>   valid only during the execution of the slot that calls this function
>   from this object's thread context.

**Update:**

For example, in your slot you can write:

```
def toogle_layer(self):
    action = QtCore.QObject.sender()

    if action == self.action1:
        # do something
    elif action == self.action2:
        # do something else
```

Comment: I tried it like this: QObject::sender() and got a syntax error.

Comment: @gustavgans, sure, because it is c++ syntax. You have to use Python syntax instead. Maybe `QtCore.QObject.sender()` will work?

Comment: I tried it like you suggests but get an AttributeError: xxx instance has no attribute 'sender'. Anyway thanks I will find out :)

Comment: @gustavgans, please take a look on my updated answer.

Comment: @vahancho. Your PyQt code snippet is not quite right: `QObject.sender` is not static, so it would throw a `TypeError` due to missing arguments. Instead, just use `action = self.sender()`.